# Dynamic autonumbering when ctrl + hit enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an autonumbering function. If  <kbd>control</kbd> +  <kbd>enter</kbd>  are pressed, it'll do an auto numbering function. The autonumbering function works now, but it has an error. When i start my autonumbering at the second textbox, the first textbox is affected too. My target is when i change only the 2nd or 3rd textbox, the textbox before them shouldn't change the value.

Please, see the image i provided for better explanation. Also, I provided a JSFIDDLE

```js
//this is my function for autonumbering
const inputAncestor = document.querySelector("tbody");

inputAncestor.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (
    e.target.matches('input.form-control') &&
    ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 10))
  ) {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
    let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    inputs.forEach((inp) => {
      if (inp !== e.target) {
        inp.value = ++value;
      }
    })
  }
})

//this is my function for adding dynamic rows.

$("#addrow").on('click', function() {

  let rowIndex = $('.auto_num').length + 1;
  let rowIndexx = $('.auto_num').length + 1;

  var newRow = '<tr><td><input class="auto_num"  type="text" value="' + rowIndexx + '" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input name="test1' + rowIndex + '" value="" class="form-control"  type="number" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input id="test' + rowIndex + '" name="test' + rowIndex + '" type="number" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input id="test' + rowIndex + '" name="test' + rowIndex + '" type="number" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow' + rowIndex + '" name="removerow' + rowIndex + '" value="Remove"/></td>';

  $("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);
});

$(document).on('click', '.removerow', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  regenerate_auto_num();
});

function regenerate_auto_num() {
  let count = 1;
  $(".auto_num").each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).val(count);
    count++;
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1" id="applicanttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>auto numbering ctrl+ enter</th>
      <th>col1#</th>
      <th>col2 #</th>
      <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row_0">
      <td>
        <input id="#" name="#" class="auto_num" type="text" value="1" readonly />
      </td>
      <td class="labelcell">
        <input value="" class="hehe form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" />
      </td>
      <td class="labelcell">
        <input name="test1" class="hehe" type="number" />
      </td>
      <td class="labelcell">
        <input name="test2" class="hehe" type="number" />
      </td>
      <td class="labelcell">
        <input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow0" name="removerow0" value="Remove">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=5><button type="button" id="addrow" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Add Row</button>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get quite that. Can i ask you to be more specific? Sorry, I'm a newbie. Thank you.

Comment: At first, remove the useless ids, those must be unique in the document, then get the collection of rows in the table, iterate through the  rows, and get the cells of the each row, then find the input from the targeted column. Cells have `cellIndex` property, rows have `rowIndex` property and `cells` collection, which you can use to identify the rows and columns to handle.